# Converting a variable created with SAS SQL 'Into:' option into a character variable so it can be used in a filepath

Tags: sql, sas

I have a dataset with a single column of character variables that I am looking to convert one row at a time using a macro into macro variables, which will then be used in a file path (this is a yahoo finance type scenario).

Anyway I know that variables created using Into: are automatically assigned the format BEST12. so I've tried using input in a data *null* step to convert the numeric variable to a string. The long says that the conversion is successful, but then when I create a dataset to test the variable using something like:

`Data test;`
`mynewvar = &mycharvar`;
`run;`

I get an error message saying the variable (displaying the correct value in the log (i.e. 'GOOG') has not been initialised. SAS then creates a dataset with two columns, one called mynewvar and one called 'GOOG'.

When i try piping this variable into a filepath to represent one part of the yahoo web address for downloading stock data it returns null values.

When i do something like:

`%let mycharvar = 'GOOG';`

then drop mycharvar into the filepath for the yahoo CSV import it works fine...

...am I doing something really obviously wrong here? I'm sure I've done this before but I cant for the life me remember how I did it.

Thanks for the help,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

You need to put double quotes around the value when you use it in the data step.

```
Data test; mynewvar = "&mycharvar"; run;
```

Macro variables "write" code for you.  They are processed before the code is compiled and run.  So when `&mycharvar` holds the value `GOOG`, your old code gets written as

```
Data test; mynewvar = GOOG; run;
```

The compiler then complains that `GOOG` has not been initialized.  If you look at the output data set, you will see a GOOG column containing a *missing* value (`.`).

Put it in double quotes and you will get what you want.